# by mistake i have dropped a table in oracle sql developer, how can I get the table back

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, drop-table

i am working on oracle sqldeveloper, i am supposed to drop the table emp12. But i have dropped the table emp1 by mistake. Is there a way, so that i can get the table emp1 again.
drop table emp1;
can we get back dropped table using flasback query.

Comment: [Retrieving a Dropped Table](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMQS/GUID-1DE547D1-3AF0-4269-8BAA-4C298EC05905.htm)

Comment: Check the recycle bin, you may be in luck!

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46834181/5841306) answer your question ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contact your database administrator, he will be able to get the data back.

Comment: He or she MAY be able to assuming they have a backup available (or flashback and recycle bin enabled) or...

Answer (score -1):

In sql developer, check in the recycle bin. There you can find dropped tables. If you don’t have access to that try with dba user.